# Image map and hover effect

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I am stuck at this problem. Is there way to make each section of this map clickable with an hover effect? I've never done something like this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read more about how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Its ideal to add code and other related script otherwise there is high chance your question will downvoted. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I just need to know that is there a way to do it or maybe some example - that's all

Answer (score 3):

I used GIMP to select an area by color but you could also manually trace simpler paths:

- Select area by color
- [Select] → [To Path]
- And from the Paths window: Right click and [Export Path...]
- Find the saved SVG files and combine all your `<path>`s into a single SVG.
- Use CSS `:hover`, `transition`, `fill`
- Use JS for the Click Events

```js
const ELS_areas = document.querySelectorAll("#my_map path");

const handleClickArea = (ev) => {
  const area = ev.currentTarget;
  console.log(area.id); // Get ID of clicked <path>
};

ELS_areas.forEach(area => {
  area.addEventListener("click", handleClickArea);
});
```

```css
svg#my_map {
  height: 180px;
  width: auto;
}

path {
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  stroke: #929ba9;
  stroke-width: 4;
  paint-order: stroke;
}

path:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  fill: gold;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg id="my_map" viewBox="0 0 431 609" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="balranald"
        fill="#a7c197"
        d="M 301,420
           C 301,420 300,424 300,424
             300,424 246,424 246,424
             246,424 246,438 246,438
             246,438 238,438 238,438
             238,438 238,445 238,445
             238,445 232,444 232,444
             231,448 228,464 224,466
             222,468 215,468 212,468
             212,468 208,487 208,487
             208,487 206,495 206,495
             206,495 201,497 201,497
             200,507 197,506 186,506
             186,506 186,510 186,510
             186,510 181,510 181,510
             181,510 181,519 181,519
             181,519 190,520 190,520
             190,520 186,541 186,541
             186,541 183,548 183,548
             183,548 167,551 167,551
             167,551 162,569 162,569
             162,569 153,573 153,573
             153,573 155,581 155,581
             156,585 157,590 163,589
             167,589 173,584 174,581
             176,577 176,571 182,570
             186,569 188,573 190,575
             192,576 196,578 199,579
             209,582 216,579 223,582
             223,582 238,591 238,591
             241,593 241,596 243,598
             245,599 252,604 255,605
             255,605 260,590 260,590
             262,585 266,584 268,580
             268,580 270,572 270,572
             272,568 275,565 277,562
             280,557 281,555 285,552
             297,542 298,548 307,543
             313,540 313,538 317,534
             318,532 320,530 322,530
             325,530 327,535 333,535
             337,536 345,534 350,533
             353,532 356,533 360,531
             363,529 366,526 369,524
             374,519 375,520 377,515
             377,515 366,515 366,515
             366,515 366,484 366,484
             359,481 361,476 361,470
             353,469 355,466 352,461
             349,453 348,457 347,447
             347,444 347,439 345,437
             343,435 335,436 333,436
             333,436 333,424 333,424
             333,424 301,420 301,420 Z" />

  <path id="wentworth_shire"
        fill="#7cd2f4"
        d="M 203,384
           C 203,384 202,398 202,398
             202,398 159,393 159,393
             159,393 162,411 162,411
             162,411 152,410 152,410
             152,410 145,409 145,409
             145,409 132,420 132,420
             132,420 112,422 112,422
             112,422 113,418 113,418
             113,418 108,418 108,418
             108,418 108,423 108,423
             108,423 68,423 68,423
             68,423 68,419 68,419
             68,419 59,419 59,419
             59,419 59,408 59,408
             53,409 47,409 42,408
             42,408 38,434 38,434
             38,434 36,444 36,444
             36,444 29,446 29,446
             29,446 5,446 5,446
             5,446 5,515 5,515
             5,515 25,516 25,516
             25,516 33,521 33,521
             33,521 40,522 40,522
             40,522 51,526 51,526
             53,527 56,529 59,528
             65,528 68,518 77,520
             80,520 82,523 86,523
             86,523 105,522 105,522
             110,522 111,525 116,526
             119,527 122,526 125,529
             130,532 127,536 130,539
             133,542 140,542 143,546
             144,549 142,554 143,560
             144,564 149,567 152,571
             152,571 162,569 162,569
             162,564 164,550 168,548
             171,546 180,549 182,546
             183,545 184,540 184,539
             184,539 187,521 187,521
             187,521 179,521 179,521
             179,521 179,508 179,508
             179,508 184,508 184,508
             184,508 184,503 184,503
             184,503 199,503 199,503
             199,503 199,495 199,495
             199,495 204,493 204,493
             204,493 207,485 207,485
             207,485 211,465 211,465
             213,465 221,467 224,465
             227,462 228,446 231,443
             232,442 234,442 236,442
             236,442 236,436 236,436
             236,436 244,436 244,436
             244,436 244,422 244,422
             244,422 263,422 263,422
             263,410 262,409 274,409
             274,409 274,402 274,402
             274,402 265,402 265,402
             265,402 265,397 265,397
             265,397 258,397 258,397
             255,400 251,402 249,397
             248,396 249,392 249,390
             249,390 203,384 203,384 Z" />

  <path id="broken_hill"
        fill="#f79226"
        d="M 5,3
           C 5,3 5,443 5,443
             5,443 35,443 35,443
             35,443 40,406 40,406
             44,406 58,404 60,408
             62,410 61,414 60,417
             60,417 71,418 71,418
             71,418 70,420 70,420
             70,420 106,421 106,421
             106,421 106,415 106,415
             111,415 113,414 115,420
             115,420 131,418 131,418
             131,418 143,407 143,407
             136,396 141,393 140,384
             138,384 136,384 135,384
             126,384 129,373 129,368
             125,368 118,368 115,366
             113,363 113,355 114,352
             114,352 114,348 114,348
             115,337 125,346 129,342
             129,342 134,331 134,331
             136,326 139,326 140,323
             141,321 140,319 143,316
             143,316 164,300 164,300
             164,300 177,286 177,286
             182,284 185,291 189,288
             191,286 189,282 189,281
             189,278 189,278 191,276
             189,273 186,270 185,268
             184,265 185,263 183,261
             180,255 178,259 178,248
             178,248 178,211 178,211
             174,211 166,213 164,209
             162,207 163,203 163,201
             163,201 178,201 178,201
             176,194 176,188 177,182
             177,177 176,174 181,173
             181,163 180,161 191,161
             191,161 191,147 191,147
             191,147 208,147 208,147
             208,143 207,135 209,133
             211,131 218,132 222,132
             230,132 249,131 257,133
             257,133 257,127 257,127
             257,127 313,127 313,127
             313,127 314,133 314,133
             321,131 320,136 322,142
             322,142 342,127 342,127
             338,125 335,126 331,127
             331,123 331,111 330,109
             327,106 316,108 316,103
             316,100 319,99 320,94
             322,87 318,79 323,70
             325,65 342,52 346,47
             352,40 348,33 349,29
             351,24 356,24 358,18
             360,10 354,11 351,9
             344,4 349,3 338,3
             338,3 5,3 5,3 Z" />

  <path id="central_darling_shire"
        fill="#eeb948"
        d="M 260,129
           C 258,135 256,134 251,135
             251,135 211,135 211,135
             211,137 211,145 209,147
             207,151 196,150 193,150
             193,150 193,164 193,164
             193,164 184,164 184,164
             184,164 184,175 184,175
             184,175 180,175 180,175
             180,175 180,204 180,204
             180,204 165,204 165,204
             165,204 165,209 165,209
             165,209 181,209 181,209
             181,209 181,248 181,248
             181,259 183,254 186,262
             185,260 192,277 192,274
             192,276 191,278 191,280
             191,283 193,285 191,288
             186,295 182,287 178,289
             178,289 168,299 168,299
             168,299 146,316 146,316
             142,320 143,323 141,325
             139,329 138,325 134,335
             133,338 132,343 129,344
             127,346 120,345 117,344
             117,344 116,365 116,365
             116,365 131,365 131,365
             131,365 131,382 131,382
             131,382 142,382 142,382
             142,382 142,390 142,390
             141,399 140,405 152,407
             152,407 159,409 159,409
             159,409 156,391 156,391
             156,391 201,395 201,395
             201,395 201,381 201,381
             201,381 252,388 252,388
             251,395 249,398 256,398
             256,398 255,395 255,395
             260,393 266,392 267,400
             267,400 276,400 276,400
             276,400 276,412 276,412
             276,412 266,412 266,412
             266,412 266,422 266,422
             266,422 298,422 298,422
             298,422 298,418 298,418
             306,418 315,419 324,421
             326,421 332,421 334,423
             336,425 336,431 336,434
             336,434 348,434 348,434
             348,434 348,437 348,437
             348,437 364,437 364,437
             364,437 372,432 372,432
             372,432 382,430 382,430
             382,430 383,423 383,423
             389,423 388,415 389,411
             389,411 404,412 404,412
             404,412 403,416 403,416
             403,416 408,416 408,416
             408,416 408,410 408,410
             408,410 420,408 420,408
             420,408 422,402 422,402
             422,402 426,383 426,383
             426,383 408,383 408,383
             408,383 408,360 408,360
             406,361 404,363 401,363
             396,364 394,360 390,359
             387,358 383,359 381,357
             379,356 379,353 377,352
             374,349 372,353 367,349
             363,347 359,340 356,338
             350,334 349,341 343,335
             336,328 339,326 337,322
             336,319 333,315 332,313
             329,313 323,316 321,316
             319,315 313,306 313,304
             313,303 317,299 319,298
             320,299 322,302 324,302
             326,303 334,298 337,297
             337,297 333,291 333,291
             333,291 359,273 359,273
             359,273 352,262 352,262
             350,262 345,264 344,264
             341,263 337,259 336,258
             336,258 320,242 320,242
             316,238 310,233 311,228
             312,224 320,218 324,216
             324,216 329,214 329,214
             332,213 332,210 335,209
             337,208 340,210 342,209
             346,208 343,203 349,198
             356,190 365,192 375,192
             375,192 333,144 333,144
             332,142 330,141 328,141
             325,140 319,147 318,138
             318,138 318,135 318,135
             313,134 311,134 311,129
             311,129 260,129 260,129 Z" />

</svg>
```

Comment: You're bloody amazing! I'll check out GIMP! 
thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you! @DionRussell you're welcome! happy SVG-ing